# iOS: Almofire PUT and DELETE Call is not working with Params in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to Put and Delete data through Almofire Library but facing issue regarding parameters. Params are missing, following are the error:

```
Response JSON data = {
    data = "<null>";
    issuccess = 0;
    msg = "{'car_id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'car_brand_id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')], 'last_oil_change': [ErrorDetail(string='Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD.', code='invalid')]} with error {  Custom error message.  }";
}
```

I am using the following code:

```
let params : [String : String] = ["brand_model_id": String(car_model_id), "oil_brand_id": String(oil_brand_id), "car_mileage": edCurrentMilage.text!, "car_modelyear": edVehicleModelYear.text!, "last_oil_change": edLastOilChange.text!]


Alamofire.request(Constants.APIURL + Constants.APIPOSTCARDATA ,method:.put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { [self] response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess,
                    let value = response.result.value else {
                                print("Error while fetching tags: \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
                                self.hideIndicator()
            //                    self.btn_submit_outlet.isEnabled = true
                                // completion(nil)
                                return
                        }
                        print(value)
                        let json = JSON.init(value as! NSDictionary)
                        print(json)
                        let code = json["issuccess"].boolValue
                        if(code)
                        {
                            self.hideIndicator()
                            Commons.showAlert(title: "Alert", error: "Data has been added.", VC: self)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            self.hideIndicator()
                            Commons.showAlert(title: String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Alert", comment: "")), error: String.localizedStringWithFormat(NSLocalizedString("Something went wrong.", comment: "")), VC: self)
                        }
                    }
```

Above mention code is used for the PUT call Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: as you see in error message just set those categories proper and output will be sure...

Comment: there you miss 2 things `car_id`, `car_brand_id ` and last part date formate should be `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: I have added these as params but server is not getting the params thats why it is sending this error @jatinfl

Comment: Which part of 'msg' do you not understand?

Comment: @ElTomato my Post call with same parameters is working fine but it is not working for PUT and returning me the error that params are missing. I want to know why parameters are not accepting in PUT or delete call?

Comment: Talk to the server guy.  Your code doesn't have 'last_oil_change.'  But if 'msg' says that's what's missing, then nobody can tell what is wrong.

Comment: the same call is working fine for android and on Postman but not i am getting this error

Comment: @ElTomato ["oil_brand_id": "3", "car_mileage": "234", "car_modelyear": "2021", "last_oil_change": "14-Jul-21", "brand_model_id": "2"] this is my body for PUT everything is there according to format

Comment: `14-Jul-21` this must be `2021-07-14` as per error message

Comment: If it's working fine in Postman, ask Postman to generate `cURL` command equivalent. You can also ask Alamofire to generate `cURL` equivalent, might be helpful to see what's wrong. Also print `params` to be sure too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not against you particularly, **BUT**, it's something that is lacking a lot in this kind of questions.

Usually, by reading output error, in our case the server response we **might**, and I insist on **"might"**, find the solution. But it's not always the case, sometimes error message is too generic, or pointing to the wrong direction. Here, error is saying about missing "car_id" param, but according to you it's not needed, so it's misleading (if we believe your saying).

Another usually good hint, is saying that "It's working on Android", "It's working in Postman", "It's working with a cURL command".

Usually, when this happen, I'm asking myself:
Why the author doesn't show the Postman, Android code, cURL command that would allow people knowing both tools/languages/platforms to spot a difference that could be the mistake.

Let's be honest, that would be easier, no? You might have quickly the right solution/fix, no? It's better than trying to guess battling agains the server response, no?

Now...

You are using Alamofire AND Postman. What if I told you that might be enough for you?

Quick trivia:
Did you know that Postman can generate code for the request?
It can even generate Swift Code for your request using `URLSession`? It's not "beautiful", "swifty" Swift code, but it's enough to spot difference and find why it's working on Postman and not in your code. 
It can also generate [cURL command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)? If you don't know about `cURL` a quick explanation would be "command line tool to make web request with params etc in Terminal.app/Bash/Shell, ie: it's basic and usually known by a lot of developers, so even if you only speak JavaScript, Java, etc, it's often like a "common language"
How? Even when I say that in comments, people don't even try to search for it... Let's find it with your favorite Search Engine, which should lead you to [this tutorial/blog post](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/). And tadaaa!
Did you know that AlamoFire can print request as `cURL` equivalent? It's stated [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#curl-command-output).

So in your case, what about asking Alamofire and Postman to generate cURL command and compare?
Then, you might want to change the parameters of the request, or even the parameters of the method `request(_:method:parameters:encoding:headers:)`.

Why I am saying this?
Because if you don't give enough informations, there will be a delay between someone asking for more info/details in comment and yourself responding to them. Also, different commenters will ask for different questions, since debugging is a skill and causes might be multiples, we might ask different things, and only one will be relevant in the end to your issue, but we can't guess which one until then.
Because spotting difference is easier and might attract quicker response.
Now that you know about POSTMAN and Alamofire and cURL, you might even find yourself the solution. Even quicker than making a question on SO! Be your own hero!
In the end, only an "attractive" question will have good answers, so give as much info as possible, don't hold them (parameters sent, equivalent android code, screenshot at least of the Postman, but know that you know about the cURL generation code). Of course, keep your private token etc, obfuscate them a little, but still, you might have watch enough TV shows/movies where holding info is bad for the main characters, why repeating that mistake here?

Answer (score -1):

As the error message says: Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD.

Please check "last_oil_change" field. The value is from edLastOilChange.text. Does edLastOilChange.text meet the required format?

Comment: no this is not the actual issue server is not getting parameters.

Comment: @MuhammadUmair You can see the request output from the console. Is the parameters correctly encoded to Json?